# Set Builder Notation of $f \circ g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

From Essential Calculus Early Transcendentals Second Edition by James Stewart, I was wondering if there was a way to write this in set builder notation:
The domain of $(f\circ g)(x)$ is the set of all x in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$.

My thought is that it would vary for each scenario correct?

Comment: What do you mean with "vary for each scenario"? $f\circ g=\{\,\langle x,y\rangle\mid \exists z\colon \langle x,z\rangle \in g\land\langle z,y\rangle \in f\,\}$

Comment: @JimH You've got it backwards in your $\operatorname{dom} f\circ g$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes, I do. Thank you ( Sometimes I forget which way we do it in modern times.)  So assuming that $f\circ g$ means do $g$ and then $f$, so $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, we have $Dom(f \circ g) = \{x|x \in Dom(g) \land g(x) \in Dom(f)\}$

Comment: @JimH so is the second part of your first comment wrong?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Yes, it should be $\{x|g(x) \in Dom(f)\}$  I am deleting my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Dom(f)$ is the domain of $f$, we can write your statement as follows:

$Dom(f\circ g)=\{x\in Dom(g)|g(x)\in Dom(f)\}$