# Spin Off Question from Set Builder Notation of f∘g

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

My question [Set Builder Notation of $f \circ g$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416683/set-builder-notation-of-f-circ-g?noredirect=1#comment4991174_2416683) was answered, and I fine with the answer, except now I am trying to apply it to this problem:

$F(p)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{p}}$

Intuitively I am separating it into 2 functions $F(u)=\sqrt{u}$, and $h(p)=2-\sqrt{p}$.  Using my answer from my previous question I got confused but I still attemped and wrote the following as its domain:

$$D:\{p\in p\ge0|2-\sqrt{p}\in u\ge0\}$$

Comment: p in p >= 0 is nonsense.

Comment: Is F a real valued function or can it have complex values?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Should it be $p \in 0 \le p\le 4$?

Comment: F is real valued

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky.  p in 0 is nonsense.

Comment: @JimH So how would I write it in the way the last answer to my question was written?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I am just trying to write it how its written in my last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the same name for both $F(p) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{p}}$ and for $F(u) = \sqrt{u}$.

Let's make $g(u) = \sqrt{u}$ so that $F = g \circ h$

If you want to write the domain as was discussed in your previous question, you would write:

$$\{p| p \in Dom(h) \land h(p) \in Dom(g)\}$$.

If you insist (or have been told) to work the whole thing out in set builder notation, then we can continue:

$$= \{p| p \ge 0 \land h(p) \in Dom(g)\}$$

$$= \{p| p \ge 0 \land 2 - \sqrt{p} \in Dom(g)\}$$

$$= \{p| p \ge 0 \land 2 - \sqrt{p}  \ge 0\}$$

$$= \{p| p \ge 0 \land 2   \ge \sqrt{p} \}$$

$$= \{p| p \ge 0 \land 4 \ge p\}$$.

I not think that there are clearer ways of telling a reader that the domain of $F$ is $\{p| 0 \le p \le 4\}$.

Compare the preceding to:

We must have $p \ge 0$ in order for $p$ to be in the domain of $h$.

Then we need $2-\sqrt{p} \ge 0$ so we can find the square root of $h(p)$.

$2-\sqrt{p} \ge 0$ if and only if $p \le 4$

So the domain of $F$ is $\{p| 0 \le p \le 4\}$.

Comment: So quick question for the $Dom(h)$ would I write out the domain of h? And same question for $Dom(g)$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of f as a real valued function is
{ x in R : 0 <= x <= 4 }.